# Load specific images first, before loading the rest of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance

#### Issue:

We have a page that loads a few hundred images (92% of the requests and bytes on the page are from images) and are looking for ways to load images within a certain div (about 20 images) before loading the rest of the images on the page.

After searching, it seems that people either use pagination or lazy loading - the client has ruled out lazy loading and neither of us want to paginate if we can help it.

---

#### Question:

Is there a simple way to force browsers to load images within a certain div (or multiple divs) before it loads the rest of the images?

---

#### Skill:

Our javascript/jquery is limited (to reading other people's instructions) - so any help or pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you should get ur images like so

```
window.on('load',function(){
//functionality to get images for the later load from server
})
```

Answer (score 0):

How about preloading images as so (place in head section):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

Image1 = new Image()
Image1.src = "image1.gif"

Image2 = new Image()
Image2.src = "image2.gif"

Image3 = new Image()
Image3.src = "image3.gif"

</script>
```

source: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/web_graphics/article.php/3480001

Another way: http://perishablepress.com/a-way-to-preload-images-without-javascript-that-is-so-much-better/

Answer (score 0):

Try this plugin http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/ . The plugin can check whether the a container (a div) has loaded all the images inside ?. After checking, if this returns true, you can load other images.

eg.

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="first images to be loaded">
    <img src="first images to be loaded">
    <img src="first images to be loaded">
    <img src="first images to be loaded">
    <img src="first images to be loaded">
    <img src="first images to be loaded">
</div>
<div id="otherImgs"><div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var imgs = ["img1.jpg","img1.jpg","img1.jpg"];
            imagesLoaded( document.querySelector('#container'), function( instance ) {
                for(i in imgs){
                    var img = $("<img />").attr('src', "test/"+imgs[i]);
                    $("#otherImgs").append(img);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```